# Why setsebool for httpd not working with -P parameter?

Tags: centos, rhel, selinux

I'm trying to disable SELinux for httpd, but when I use the the `setsebool` command with -P parameter, it doesn't work:

```
setsebool -P http_can_network_connect 1
```

**Nothing happens** *when I do that ie, the command is apparently running, but returns nothing, and bash is freeze. I'll wait for 10~30 minutes, and nothing happens.*

Why?

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: Nothing happens. Nothing is return, just freeze the bash (and doesn't write in SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://serverfault.com/questions/259958/how-to-disable-selinux-for-apache-httpd-only-on-my-fedora-14) might help, with good references for further reading. What you want to do isn't possible directly, but there are workarounds.